# Can text-independent writer identification be done without multi-sentence training datasets for each writer?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, ai-design, natural-language-understanding

I am trying to learn more about text-independent writer identification and was hoping for some advice.

I have a folder with 100k images, each of them with a different handwritten sentence. All of the images have sentences of different lengths. They range from about 30 to 80 English characters. The file names start at `1.png` and go up to `100k.png`. That's it, as far as input data. 95% of the sentences are written by different writers. 5% are written by the same writers. Some writers might have written 2 sentences, while others 300+.

Does anyone know of an identification method that would be able to determine what images were written by the same writer?

I know that most methods require each writer to have provided a full page of sample writing for training, but, of course, I do not have that.

Comment: I have edited your post to clarify it. Make sure that I did not change the meaning of your sentences.

Comment: Is the data labeled, i.e. do you know which sentence has been produced by which writer? If so, I'd start out training a Recurrent Neural Network, which is specialized on working with sequence data.